# CodeFights Interview Practice- Dynamic Programing : Basic : fillingBlocks

Tags: dynamic

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgQje.png)

Can anyone help me solve this problem? 
i hope for a detailed explaination since i'm newbie. or maybe just give me the source code, sincerely thanks, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope that help you:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/664113/count-the-ways-to-fill-a-4-times-n-board-with-dominoes

Final formula:
f(n)=f(n−1)+5f(n−2)+f(n−3)−f(n−4).